# Is NSStream.close() synchronous wrt TCP?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, cocoa-touch, tcp

I have input and output NSStream's as part of a TCP connection after using `NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName()`. If I call the [`close()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSStream/close) method on those input and output streams, then by the time the functions return, will my TCP connection be in the [CLOSED](http://ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/Graphics/tcpStateDiagram1.gif) state?

If not, how could I determine the time at which the underlying TCP connection actually closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the answer is *no*, the TCP connection will not necessarily be in the CLOSED state. To make sure the TCP connection does a graceful close and find out when that happens, one must use a lower-level API than `NSStream`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Closing the stream** terminates the flow of bytes and **releases system
>   resources that were reserved for the stream** when it was opened. If the
>   stream has been scheduled on a run loop, closing the stream implicitly
>   removes the stream from the run loop. A stream that is closed can
>   still be queried for its properties.

```
var streamStatus: NSStreamStatus { get }
```

> The receiver’s status

```
enum NSStreamStatus : UInt {
    case NotOpen
    case Opening
    case Open
    case Reading
    case Writing
    case AtEnd
    case Closed
    case Error
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Seems to me you just copy/pasted the text I linked to.

Comment: Closing the stream terminates the flow of bytes and releases system resources. If the underlying resource is the file or socket, when you close the stream, the the system releases system resources. in your case, release socket (if there is no other associated stream. even though you are using low level API like direct socket functions, when you close the socket, there is no guaranty how long the TCP stack will still use it. TCP stack is responsible for this. there is big difference between closing TCP connection, and release the socket.

Comment: if you close your streams, the peer party will be advice 'immediately'. but there is no guaranty about timing.'immediately' means time up to seconds ... for you there is no difference. once closed, the stream is no usable again for data transfer

Comment: if the socket is not configured with SO_REUSE.... the system can hold it before release for tens of seconds, typically 20 seconds

Comment: The close() call deletes a descriptor from the per-process object refer-
     ence table.  If this is the last reference to the underlying object, the
     object will be deactivated.

Comment: theoretically you can poll for the events on the underlying socket, but there is no practical reason for it, if you use NSStream

Comment: Oh I can poll for the events? How could I determine the time at which the underlying TCP connection actually closes? I'm doing a performance experiment about TCP and I would like to timestamp the close event for a benchmark.

Comment: @EthanP, performance experiment about TCP with using NSStream API? oh man, what are you talking about?!  generally for all system API check your man pages.

Comment: Hmm. Although I do believe that you're trying to be helpful, I don't think you're succeeding. If you don't believe my technique is a good way to go could you offer me an alternative route or at least a reason why it is not good?

Comment: @EthanP i am not sure what you want to implement. if you are able to explain what exactly you want to do, i will do my best to help you. you are working with NSStreams. if you close the NSStream, the stream is not accessible when the function returns. the key information is "closing the stream implicitly removes the stream from the run loop". you don't have any way to use the underlaying socket, or file or ......